How can I automate uploading a PFX Client Certificate for Azure AD B2C custom policies
Can anyone point me to a functioning process to automate the upload of a client certificate (PFX/Password) to Azure AD B2C as a Policy Key for a Custom Policy?
I can manually upload the certificate no problem and while I've got all the other policy keys to be automated just fine, but handling the PFX by automation is proving to be problematic.
I've got the the basics of communication down using the b2cadmin Jwks Web API that's used in the Azure Portal, but I'm struggling to reproduce the payload that needs to be sent in the body of the POST request. I tried to use ChatGPT to help me reverse engineer the documentation, but I'm struggling to create a working payload.

To upload PFX certificates you must POST to the Graph Beta endpoint trustFramework/keySets/{policyKeyId}/uploadPkcs12
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/trustFramework/keySets/{id}/uploadPkcs12
Content-type: application/json

{
  "key": "Base64-encoded-pfx-content",
  "password": "password-value"
}

You can read more about this endpoint, alongside other code samples, on the Microsoft Documentation
Note: you need to have the role delegated or application permission TrustFrameworkKeySet.ReadWrite.All to perform this action.

Perfect, thanks so much, I'll have a look at this. I had tried the graph beta endpoint for other things unsuccessfully so I'd given up on it and switched to using the same method as used by the Azure Portal, but this particular activity I struggled to reproduce.
